# How do I change the password using veracrypt on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, veracrypt

To the best of my knowledge, there is no gui for the linux version of veracrypt (I'm running Ubuntu), which is fine, but I wanted to change the password of an encrypted drive and cannot figure out how to do it.

I have tried a number of combinations of options with `-C` and `--new-password`, but nothing seems to work. The version that seems most logical (and gets past the basic validation checks is `veracrypt -C --new-password=password`). I get various errors after being prompted for the current credentials and I run into `VeraCrypt::File::Open:232` regardless of whether the partition is mounted (decrypted) or not, which seems weird.

If someone knows how to do this or is able to figure it out, would you please be so kind as to post the exact command you used (with any real passwords redacted, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is to run veracrypt with elevated rights:

```
sudo veracrypt --change /dev/sdX
```

the `/dev/sdX` is the drive or file location. you will be asked to provide current password, PIM and keyfile if you have one. If you provided the correct data you will be asked for new password, PIM, keyfile (if you want one) and 320 random characters.

hope this helps!

Comment: I try to be a good user and NOT use sudo liberally, so I didn't think to try that. I was convinced it was something simple, but had no idea what to try next. The suggested command worked perfectly. Thank you!